# FOS UserBundle wrong Output

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

i have a problem with the use of FOS UserBundle.

When i call the register Action the form is named like this.

```
form.username
form.email
form.password
form.password_confirmation
```

If i want to send a confirmation email the message is this

```
registration.email.message
```

Another question would be, how can I add more information to the user manual? So that he may enter in the Registration Name, birthday, place of residence or the like.

I think it's wrong translation, right?

Can u tell me, what going wrong?

Comment: Have you read the installation instructions carefully?

Comment: Oh damn.. Sorry for my Fail. I dont commit the app/config/config.yml on live Server...

But now i dont know how i can create extra informations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your User class you can add any property you want and extend the user with the information needed. Then you need to extend the registration and profile form types and tell FOSUserBundle the exact classes. From then on, your extended forms are used in registration and co.

The documentation on [Overriding Default FOSUserBundle Forms](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md) is a good starting point.